# Tor network, Connection has timed out

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

After i connected to the tor network,it seems i can't access anything.
Here is the log-file

```
7/8/2015 6:49:33 AM.170 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
7/8/2015 6:49:33 AM.360 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
7/8/2015 6:49:36 AM.746 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
7/8/2015 6:49:36 AM.746 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
7/8/2015 6:49:43 AM.695 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 10 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-07-08 08:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
7/8/2015 6:49:43 AM.695 [NOTICE] Our directory information is no longer up-to-date enough to build circuits: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 6:49:43 AM.695 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 6:49:44 AM.740 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 6:50:00 AM.735 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
7/8/2015 6:50:07 AM.340 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
7/8/2015 6:51:36 AM.140 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 6:56:55 AM.930 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 6:57:37 AM.299 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 6:58:55 AM.359 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 6:58:55 AM.359 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:06:55 AM.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 7:13:35 AM.801 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 7:15:35 AM.321 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:15:35 AM.321 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:20:01 AM.159 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 7:22:01 AM.305 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:22:01 AM.305 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:22:01 AM.313 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 7:22:26 AM.878 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 37 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-07-08 09:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
7/8/2015 7:22:26 AM.878 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 7:24:01 AM.314 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 7:37:20 AM.694 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 8:02:26 AM.677 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 57 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-07-08 10:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
7/8/2015 8:02:26 AM.678 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
7/8/2015 8:31:19 AM.876 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 8:31:19 AM.927 [WARN] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed]. 
7/8/2015 8:33:19 AM.418 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 8:34:55 AM.836 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/8/2015 8:35:19 AM.753 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 8:36:55 AM.760 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
7/8/2015 8:36:55 AM.760 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)
```